# Manipulate or capture EditText input efficiently

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textwatcher

### **What i'm trying to achieve**

I want to convert every char the user inputs to another char and display it in the `EditText`.

### **What i've done**

My first approach is implemented using a [`TextWatcher`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html).

```
     private val textWatcher2 = object : TextWatcher {
        private var byUser = true

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {


        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            if (!byUser) return

            byUser = false

            val t = this@ManipulatingEditText.text.toString()
            val m = convert(t.last())
            val s = t.substring(0, t.length - 1) + m
            this@ManipulatingEditText.setText("")
            this@ManipulatingEditText.setText(s)
            this@ManipulatingEditText.setSelection(this@ManipulatingEditText.text!!.length)

            byUser = true
        }
    }

    /*This is just an mock of my real implementation. But the same delay occurs*/
    fun convert(c: Char) : String {
        return c.toString()
    }
```

This is working: Every new input char is converted via the convert(Char) function. Unfortunately this solution **is incredibly slow** and **inefficient**. There is a short delay after each input and you can't type fast.

This solution is not suitable for a production app. But i have not found another solution yet (Debouncing or deffering via RxJava doesn't work because some chars get skipped or race conditions apply) that works better.

Any ideas, solutions or help is appreciated.

Comment: please add logic of convert method

Comment: I included it @MoustafEL-Saghier

Comment: is your logic differ for char 'a' depend on its previous or it is fixed for each 'a'?

Comment: it's deterministic. Each char always gets converted to the same char every time.

Comment: why not make `hashMap` for doing that? so that you get rid of the process of creating the same logic for each char? it built for one time and store result in the `hashMap`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed a few things and saw a big decrease in lagginess, though I can't say which had the most (if any) impact:

- replaced calls to `setText` with manipulating the `Editable` directly
- moved the text manipulation from the `onTextChanged` callback to the `afterTextChanged` callback, since that's the callback that gives us an `Editable` and not a `CharSequence`
- simplified the logic around deciding what the new text is going to be--hopefully this is still doing what you intended; it's a bit unclear to me from the sample code you provided

  ```
  private val textWatcher2 = object : TextWatcher {
       private var byUser = true

       override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
           if (!byUser) return

           byUser = false
           s?.let {
               if (s.isNotEmpty()) {
                   s.replace(s.length - 1, s.length, convert(s.last()))
               }
           }
           byUser = true
       }

       override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
       }

       override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
       }
   }
  ```